# QDataStream and byte order in Big Endian

Tags: c++, qt, rgb, endianness, qdatastream

I have a program which sends images over the network. I manually create pixels (using `QRgb` class) and I insert them into `QDataStream`. It is quite easy when there are 16 or 32 bits per pixel (I can insert `quint16` or `quint32`), but in RGB888 (24 bits per pixel) I have to use three `quint8` variables. But I'm not sure the order of bytes when `QDataStream` has:

```
// output is QDataStream object
output.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
```

Should I insert in that order to correctly read this stream later?

```
// red, green and blue are quints8
output << blue;
output << green;
output << red;
```

EDIT: I know that setting `BigEndian` doesn't matter when I use only `quint8` but I want to put colors in such order, as in the case when Qt makes byte resorting (`quint32`  and `setByteOrder`).

Comment: If you write blue, green, red as quint8 then the byte order setting makes no difference.  :-/  Byte order only matters when writing out things that are more than one byte long.  So the only issue you need to deal with is who is reading.  Are you writing the reading code also?  If not, you have to deal with the expectations the reader has.  If you are writing it, then just read in the same order you wrote.  Note that BigEndian is the default; you don't need to set that.

Comment: No, I don't write reading code. Person, who will be reading it, knows  endianness, number of bits per pixel and format (RGB888, ARGB etc.) so way of reading should be the same regardless of format.

Comment: Then it's not clear what your question is.  That will put a blue byte, then a green byte, then a red byte.  If that's the order the reader expects (and they are expecting a 24 bit color value in the first place), then it is the right order.  If they expect a different order, it's wrong.  The reader's expectation entirely defines what you have to do...if you cannot change it.  They won't receive any indication of what byte order you set inside the QDataStream object; that affects the writing side only.